# Stacking and unstacking

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a month-status index:

```
                            var1          var2
      date status                            
2003-01-01  foo     5.673044e+12  1.412815e+10
            fubar   5.102315e+11  1.226870e+09
2003-02-01  foo     4.058879e+12  1.092852e+10
            fubar   5.761504e+11  1.745472e+09
2003-03-01  foo     6.238392e+12  1.343086e+10
```

To which I want to join a df that contains VALUE with is only date specific. So I do

```
df = df.unstack(level='status')
test = df.join(otherDf, how='left')
```

Which works as expected, now I have:

```
             (var1, foo)  (var1, fubar)   (var2, foo)  (var2, fubar)  VALUE
date                                                                       
2003-01-01  5.673044e+12   5.102315e+11  1.412815e+10   1.226870e+09   68.9
2003-02-01  4.058879e+12   5.761504e+11  1.092852e+10   1.745472e+09   69.2
2003-03-01  6.238392e+12   8.801683e+11  1.343086e+10   1.165204e+09   68.9
2003-04-01  6.077365e+12   7.515224e+11  1.228901e+10   1.315599e+09   69.0
2003-05-01  6.924681e+12   6.021974e+11  1.358737e+10   1.171898e+09   68.8
```

But now I have problems getting it back to the original format:

I naively tried `test.stack(level='status')`, which gave me

```
KeyError: 'Level status must be same as name (None)'
```

I suppose the issue is that VALUE does not have an upper level. A similar operation is not described in the [manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html). Isn't there a way to apply `stack` only to some columns?

My expected output is

```
                    var                  VALUE
      date  status                            
2003-01-01  foo     5.673044e+12  1.412815e+10   
            fubar   5.102315e+11  1.412815e+10   
2003-02-01  foo     4.058879e+12  1.092852e+10   
            fubar   5.761504e+11  1.092852e+10   
2003-03-01  foo     6.238392e+12  1.343086e+10
```

Comment: Are your possible statuses `emp` and `unemp`, or `foo` and `fubar`?

Comment: @ASGM: '0.15.2'. I just checked, this is  due to me having many columns, I just reported one, `var`, for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't unstack in the first place:

```
#df = df.unstack(level='status')
test = df.join(otherDf)
```

`join()` is smart enough to match up the indices from `otherDf` to the larger number of indices in `df` without you unstacking and re-stacking.