# Pivot and plot data

Tags: python, pandas

Disclaimer: [I had posted a related question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172124/stacking-and-unstacking), where the trick suggested (don't unstack at all for the join) was useful for that part, but in the end I actually want to unstack for various reasons (including plotting).

So here's my data:

```
                         var1        var2
date       status                        
2003-01-01 foo      69.037500  487.713615
           fubar    69.037500  563.257104
2005-01-01 foo      69.833333  479.454816
           fubar    69.833333  630.014694
2007-01-01 foo      69.137500  465.405122
```

Note that `var2`  is `(date, status)` specific, but `var1` is only specific for a given date - it is the same for both status.

Therefore, despite it being 2 status and 2 variables, its effectively only 3 time series. And I would like to reformat the data frame to reflect that. My desired output is

```
                var1    var2_foo var2_fubar
date                          
2003-01-01 69.037500  487.713615 563.257104
2005-01-01 69.833333  479.454816 630.014694
2007-01-01 69.137500  465.405122        NaN
```

Then I could plot these quite nicely on the relevant scale using

```
df.plot(secondary_y = ['var1'])
```

My attempts to get this were partially described in the other question, but one way in particular I was trying was `pivot`:

### Attempt: Pivot var2, then merge again

```
df1 = df.reset_index().pivot(index='date', columns='status', values='var2' )
```

does almost work, but it completely drops the other column.

```
status             foo       fubar
date                              
2003-01-01  487.713615  563.257104
2005-01-01  479.454816  630.014694
2007-01-01  465.405122  565.706308
2009-01-01  440.538986  465.306299
2011-01-01  420.217694  419.310829
2013-01-01  439.222659  618.119540
```

Here's my attempt to merge afterwards:

```
df2 = aggStandard.reset_index(level=1)['var1']
date
2003-01-01    69.037500
2003-01-01    69.037500
2005-01-01    69.833333
2005-01-01    69.833333
2007-01-01    69.137500
Name: var1, dtype: float64
pd.merge(df1,df2)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
foo.join(bar)
TypeError: Argument 'left' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)
```

Comment: What if you just changed the index from date/status to date/var1/status?  Or alternatively just do a merge after your pivot to bring back the missing column?

Comment: @JohnE: These sound like workarounds. If there's no cleaner way to do this, yeah, I would settle for that, but I expected there to be a better way to do this...

Comment: Yeah, they are just workarounds. I can't really think of a way to make pivot do what you want.  I suspect you might have better luck using stack/unstack than pivot though.

Comment: @JohnE I managed the workaround, but it took me some time: I needed to (i) recast the column as a data frame, (ii) use join, not merge/append.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I guess you got it, but in case this is helpful (and is a variation on what @ASGM did):

```
In [67]: df2 = df.unstack('status').iloc[:,1:]

In [68]: df2.columns = [['var1','var2_foo','var2_fubar']]

In [69]: df2
Out[69]: 
                 var1    var2_foo  var2_fubar
date                                         
2003-01-01  69.037500  487.713615  563.257104
2005-01-01  69.833333  479.454816  630.014694
2007-01-01        NaN  465.405122         NaN
```

Comment: Almost there! How would I reshape these to not have stacked column names? I need to have only one level as in `var1`, `var2_foo` `var2_fuubar`. I'm trying to get this going for hours now. In an extended problem, I have many more columns than just `var1`, and then `unstack()` seems to be the only option.

Comment: Just rename columns, I believe.  I'll tweak the answer.

Comment: I tried. Renames successfully labels in the first layer, but doesn't remove the layers.

Comment: Did you do it via ```df2.columns =``` as above?  That removed the levels (flattened it) for me whereas ```df.rename``` did not.

Answer (score 0):

Having seen your original question, I think you'd be better off doing the join after the unstacking.  Take `df` from your original question, unstack it along the `status` level, then select everything from the top-level column `"var"`, and *then* do the join after that's done.

```
df.unstack("status")["var"].join(otherDf)
```

`join()` will still be smart enough to match with the appropriate indices.  If you want to rename `foo` and `fubar` appropriately, you can use `rename`:

```
df.rename(columns={'foo': 'var_foo', 'fubar': 'var_fubar'})
```